# htaccess: redirect old domain and all pages to a new domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I know that there is a lot of examples on Stackoverflow but I still miss something.

I'm trying to redirect http://old.domain.com/fr/ to http://brand.new-domain.com/fr/ with the following rules, but that doesn't work:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add a trailing slash to paths without an extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect domain
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^other-old.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://brand.new-domain.com/$1 [r=301,L]

# Remove index.php
# Uses the "exclude method"
# http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/#Exclude_List_Method
# This method seems to work best for us, you might also use the include method.
# http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/#Include_List_Method
# Exclude root files
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php) [NC]
# Exclude EE folders
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|ee-admin|images|templates|themes|fr|nl)/ [NC]
# Exclude user created folders
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|css|img|js|swf|uploads)/ [NC]
# Exlude favico, robots, ipad icon
RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|pple-touch-icon\.png) [NC]
# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(URL=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It correctly redirect when I call the root URL, but not when I call a page. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Pv

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When writing `mod_rewrite` rules, the rules get applied in the order that they appear.

**To redirect an old domain to a new domain, you'll want that rule to be first** in your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file — all other rules should appear after it.

If you only want to *redirect a certain directory*, the following rule will do so, while allowing the rest of the site to function normally:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Only Matching Directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(fr|fr/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://brand.new-domain.com/fr/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you want to redirect the entire site, the following rule will do so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Entire Site to New Domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^other-old.domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://brand.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you care about letting crawlers know your content has moved and want to make the transition as seamless as possible, be sure to keep the [301 Redirect](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633) flag in the RewriteRule.

This will ensure that users and search engines are directed to the correct page.

---

While we're on the subject, as part of the EE 2.2 release, EllisLab now "officially" offers limited technical support for [removing index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html).

Simply add or update your code to the following, making sure to consider any rules you may already have in place:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
    # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the following ruke as the first one:

```
# Redirect domain
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^other-old.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://brand.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also mind the upper case `R` with is the short form for the lower case `redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) simple redirect instructions (a core module that you have), before trying the hacky-mod-rewrite thing?

I would do a VirtualHost with `ServerName old.domain.com` and in this VH I would add this rule:

```
Redirect /fr http://brand.new-domain.com/fr
```

from doc:

> Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the target URL.

So get a separate VirtualHost for brand.new-domain.com (with `ServerName brand.new-domain.com`) and in this one do not set the Redirect Rule.

If you still want to handle the 2 domains in the same VirtualHost then you'll have to use mod-rewrite as even RedirectMatch cannot check the request domain on the query.